# Excel Macro is not closing CSV files when process is done

Tags: excel, vba

I am running following script and it seems like its not closing and the files when script is run . How can I edit the script so that it can close the script .

```
Sub LoopFiles()

    Dim MyFileName As String, MyPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    MyPath = "C:\macro\"

    MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")

    ChDir "C:\macro\csv"

    Do Until MyFileName = ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xlsx") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        MyFileName = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use close method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223835(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line: `ActiveWorkbook.Close False`

in the space I have demonstrated below.

```
Do Until MyFileName = ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xlsx") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        MyFileName = Dir
Loop
```

or for a cleaner version do this:

```
Dim wkb as Workbook

Do Until MyFileName = ""
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName)
   With wkb
       .SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xlsx") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
       .Close False
   End With
Loop
```